# How to install Git for Cygwin?

Tags: github, cygwin

I see some tutorials online but they only show how to install git onto Cygwin AS you are installing Cygwin. I already have cygwin installed and customized so I'd prefer not to repeat that step. How do I install the git framework so I can use it for github?

Thank you.

Comment: Using a Cygwin-flavored Git could generally cause issues with NPM/yarn/scoop as they try to pass a Windows path, and it won't work. Use with care.

Comment: @DavidRefoua This is not true. You can set the CYGWIN environment variable in `cygwin.bat` to include `nodosfilewarning`, and you should be able to pass it "MS-DOS" style paths just fine (as well as POSIX-style paths).  You can read the documentation [here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html).

Comment: @rubynorails I believe I was unclear, as I meant the path that is actually _read from_ git, nit _passed to_. Read [here](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/issues/2221#issuecomment-384790821) for some details where this issue happened when I used Cygwin's Git installation together with scoop, instead of using GfW.

Comment: @DavidRefoua these days when I run Windows, I use both Git for Windows and Git from Cygwin. I prefer to use the Chocolatey package manager for my Windows programs. You can just install Chocolatey and then run `cinst /y git`, and you can install Git for Windows from the command line.  It will be in your Windows `%PATH%`, and when you run a `bash` shell with MinTTY or whatever, the version of Git installed via Cygwin will be in your `$PATH` there.

Comment: @rubynorails Coincidentally, Chocolatey is my favorite Windows package manager too, and I happen to use a dual Git setup as well. However, there is always the disadvantage of maintaining _two_ separate installations of Git on the same machine -- which I'd prefer to avoid, if I coult. The funny thing is that **GoW** project is built upon `mingw`, which despite having `pacman`, lacks many of the useful packages built for Cygwin.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the world of Cygwin, there is really no such thing as *only* installing a package *AS* you are installing Cygwin.  Cygwin was inherently designed with a setup.exe to be run *multiple* times when necessary.

There are thousands of packages available in the Cygwin repo mirrors.  From what you are saying, it sounds as if you had a single go-round with the setup file and then planned to never install any additional available packages or upgrade them in the future.  This is what the Cygwin setup file is specifically used for.

If you don't currently have Git installed in your particular Cygwin environment, just run setup.exe again and select the package.  It should automatically detect your current installation directory and package directory and previously-selected mirror.  When you mark the Git package for installation, it will automatically download all dependencies, just like apt-get or any other *NIX package manager.

There is also an abandoned project called `apt-cyg` that I still use religiously, especially on remote systems over SSH in order to avoid the GUI setup.exe.  `apt-cyg` is basically a shell script that will install your package directly from the command line, `apt-get`-style.  It requires `wget` and `subversion`,  but after the 30 seconds it takes to setup, you'd just run `apt-cyg install git`.  It also installs dependencies, just like the GUI setup.exe.

There is also a similar alternative if you install Cygwin via Chocolatey package manager -- you can also install `cyg-get` (I believe it's called).  The syntax is a bit different -- something like `cyg-get git`.  I don't really like this method, because it differs from apt-cyg in the fact that it actually uses the setup.exe and just automates the process so that you don't have to click anything.  I don't use this method, because the last I checked, Chocolatey only supported 32-bit Cygwin installs, which is also what the cyg-get package looks for.

`apt-cyg` may be abandoned, but it has yet to disappoint, and if I know what I'm looking for, I always prefer it over running the setup.exe for package installation.

It looks like the project has been picked back up and is under active development again: https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg

It appears this version requires lynx to install.  I don't know.  I still just use the original version on Google Code that worked just fine the last I checked: https://code.google.com/p/apt-cyg/

*Edit: There has been a new Cygwin package manager out for awhile called `cyg-get` that can be installed via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). 
 I'm not sure if it only works for Chocolatey-installed Cygwin installations or not, as Chocolatey doesn't install Cygwin in the normal locations anymore by default.  Feel free to comment, but `cyg-get` is now my Cygwin package manager of choice unless I'm running an older installation of Cygwin that was not installed by Chocolatey.  I avoided it for a while because they only supported 32-bit installations, but I can confirm that Chocolatey now supports 64-bit installations of Cygwin, and the `cyg-get` package manager works perfectly with it.  I have a function sourced from my `~/.bashrc` where I can use either `apt` or `apt-get` (with or without the `install` parameter, and it will just call `cyg-get.bat` with the programs I have specified to install.*

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I understand completely how it works now. Hope this post helps others who end up here through search engines.

Comment: I have a cygwin terminal, but that is it... I don't have a setup.exe on this system.

Comment: im not seeing apt-cyg on my copy of cygwin, has it been deprecated?  is there a modern replacement?

Comment: @blamb - apt-cyg does not come with Cygwin. You have to install it separately.  The GitHub URL is in my answer.

Comment: Nope. There's no "cyg-get" in the setup. Nor "apt-cyg".

Comment: @user3285866 those are alternate command line package managers that you can use to install it.  Note that my first recommendation was to use the plain ol' Cygwin setup file. Please re-read the answer or install Git-Bash instead.

Comment: @CarloWood it's simple - just re-download the setup file [https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe](https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe).

Answer (score 0):

http://redmine.jamoma.org/projects/1/wiki/Installing_and_setting_up_GIT
By following the steps mentioned in the link for windows you can install git using cygwin

Answer (score 0):

Try `winget install -e --id Git.MinGit`

The command installs a specific version of Git, identified as MinGit, using the Windows Package Manager (**winget**). The `-e` flag ensures the installation of the exact specified version, and `--id Git.MinGit` specifies the unique identifier for the Git package to be installed. In summary, this command precisely installs the Git package with the identifier MinGit, leveraging the *Windows Package Manager*.

Comment: Please add code explanation.