# Running git hooks written in shell through eclispe neon in windows

Tags: git

I have installed e-git in my rational application developer which uses eclipse neon version. I have installed cygwin for windows 10 64 bit . Installed git also and set the bin folder of cygwin in environment variables. However my git hooks are still not triggered through Rational application developer IDE , git functionality works fine when running the hook in git bash.

I have written the git hook in shell and I am using Rational application developer IDE with eclipse neon version running on windows 10 64 bit.

Can some one suggest what am I doing wrong and how to go about so that the git hook gets triggered when I commiting files to git repository using rational application developer IDE

Answer (score 0):

Do not install cygwin at all, as it might conflict with the git bash coming with Git itself.
Make sure cygwin is not in your PATH, and then launch Eclipse (and Rational application developer IDE), in order to test if the hook is triggered.

The [OP Chai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5962507/chai) took the opposite approach [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684293/running-git-hooks-written-in-shell-through-eclispe-neon-in-windows#comment86441550_49685539):

> We need to install Cygwin and correct git package

See more at "[How to install Git for Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33006313/6309)".

Comment: I have removed cygwin from path variables and also uninstalled cygwin on my windows machine. The git hook does not get triggered when I am trying the commit changes to repository

Comment: What hook did you setup?

Comment: @Chai Can you edit your question with the full path and filename for that hook?

Comment: Hi @VonC I have figured out how to make it work.We need to install Cygwin and correct git package.It is  working now for me.

Comment: @Chai Great! But again, Cygwin should not have been needed here.

Comment: @Chai I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.